# How to prevent NFS server from registering to portmap

Tags: rpc, nfs

I found how to unregister NFS server from portmap using `rpcinfo -d`, but I would like to force nfs not to register once it starts running

I mean - if I use the command `service nfs restart` - the server should not show at `rpcinfo -p` after the restart is complete

I'm using CentOS 6.5, NFS version 3

the reason why I need this is because I'm running a proxy server from the same machine as the NFS server. the proxy signs to portmap as nfs, and I want all NFS calls to be redirected to the NFS proxy and not the NFS server - and then the proxy will forward messages to the server

Comment: You should state your OS version/distribution and NFS version, etc. If you're not using portmapper for anything else, you could disable it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nfs client by itself doesn't register at rpcbind. However, the `service nfs start` starts `rpc-statd` daemon, which registers at rpcbind. Thus you have to disable `rpc-statd` daemon.

**Notice** that rpc-statd is required for file locking protocol, used by nfs v3.